# How do I resolve a `vagrant up` issue

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, ubuntu-20.04, vagrantfile, virtualbox-guest-additions

I have been trying to run `vagrant up` but I keep getting an error, though I have run a command for the box `vagrant init ubuntu/focal64` and the result said I am ready to `vagrant up` but I keep getting the error message as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: This screenshot shows where the vagrant box was initialized]

[image: This image shows vagrant up and the error message result]

Please how can I resolve this issue?
I am in need of quick help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable virtualization within the BIOS of your machine. When you first boot the computer, there's usually a screen saying "Hit F2" or "Hit Del" to enter setup (the key varies per motherboard manufacturer). You need to go into the BIOS setup and enable Hardware Virtualization support (VT-x on Intel machines). Consult your computer/motherboard manufacturer manual.

Comment: Thank you so much @djsumdog your answer helped me get through the challenge. The Challenge was that, my pc uses a Legacy BIOS and hence can't enable virtual box, so i had to convert Legacy BIOS to UEFI by upgrading it using an advance Restart from from my system Recovery in settings. Thank you once again.